# How do I make an App-Store-esque buy button?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I am adding in app purchases to an app and I want to make purchase buttons similar to the iOS App Store buttons. It is a bit difficult to make the text look right within the button. This is what I have so far:

```
let buyButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 24))
buyButton.setTitle("$0.99", for: [])
buyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4
buyButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue().cgColor
buyButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
buyButton.setTitleColor(tintColor, for: [])
buyButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
buyButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
```

Does anyone know the correct size, corner radius, and font specs of the App Store buttons? I think the text is supposed to be a bit more bold. Here are some screenshot comparisons. Mine is the red one.

[image: app store buy button]

[image: my buy button]

Comment: It's the system bold font I guess, have you tried to render with: buyButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)

Comment: the bold looks too bold. Is there something between bold and regular?

Comment: medium and semibold are between regular and bold

Comment: how can I set that?

Comment: See http://iosfonts.com